# Restore the table runner

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

The holidays are coming.  Time to get out the beautiful [table runner](https://www.target.com/p/snowflake-design-runner-red-saro-lifestyle/-/A-81625917) my grandmother quilted by hand...

[image: table_runner_gif]

Oh, no!  Moths got to it!

Can you help me to restore it?

For those who prefer text only:

```
RGSRMVRB
EOAEEAEY
MTNGTLRD
SOHIIOES
DEMSNLER
DEHEITED
REPSAREP
SEHEITAR
DESSRNEV
DEHEIVAD
RECSINEB
RETLINAS
  MSINEC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The table runner was constructed so that

> for every pair of adjacent rows, the red letters spell a word left to right, and the greens spell a word right to left.
>
>  For instance, the top two rows have ROSEMARY in red; the second and third overlap to make MONETARY, and then the third and fourth make MONITORS. At the same time, the greens running right-to-left spell BEVERAGE, DELEGATE, DELIGHTS.
>
>
>  [image: image with spelled words shown]
>
>  Continuing this pattern, we get _EMLINES and CANIST_R in the last two rows, which can only be filled by **H** and **E**.

Comment: rot 13 (V guvax "crevfurf" jbhyq or n orggre svg sbe gur 4gu ebj...)

Comment: @Quark-epoch Huh? I'm not sure what you mean by a "better fit" - the words are given by a strict pattern, and that word is not in there.

Comment: im sorry i really didn't know how this kind of puzzle works ... I realised what you mean now!

Comment: Minor correction: rot13(Lbh unir "ERCRAGRQ" ba gur sbhegu ebj - vg fubhyq or "ERCRNGRQ".  Vebavpnyyl nyzbfg n "ercrng" bs "ERCRNGRE"...)